# "Process finished with exit code 139" in CLion IDE while the program is running fine in the terminal

Tags: segmentation-fault, clion

I am working on a software project, which can be build by invoking `cmake`, `make` and `make install`. The IDE I am using is JetBrains' CLion.

The thing that I do not understand is that when I run the program in CLion, I get this feedback:

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

However, when I run the program in a terminal, it works flawlessly.
When I use the CLion debugger, Assembly code is presented to me and I don't know why (see screenshot below).
[image]

I don't know how I should debug this issue. Apologies if my issue is a duplicate, in this case I'd be happy if one could show me the "original".

I should also mention that (although feeling quite comfortable with my Ubuntu 20.04) I am still fairly new to Linux/Unix in general and also not a master of the C language.

Thanks in advance for any hints, help or pushes in the right direction! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to figure it out.

I added the line `set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug )` to the CMakeLists.txt file at the root level of the project.
By doing to, I enabled the debug functionality of CLion. Hence, I was able to break at the point where the segmentation fault happens and to successfully debug it.

(In case someone is interested: What caused the segmentation fault was that a `strrchr(const char *str, int c)` function was called with `str` being NULL. `str` was holding the file name that the program would read. The reason the program worked on the terminal was that I navigated to the folder containing the file and executed the program. In the CLion configuration, I added the path in "global form". By providing a path relative to the executable file inside the CLion project solved the issue for me.)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this with CLion 2022.1.3 and what ultimately worked was clearing all my breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing all your variables in your watchlist. This worked for me, since the variables I was watching while debugging where either changed or not available anymore and the debugger couldn't handle it.